# Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm new to web programming so it is quite possible that the problem here is embarrassingly obvious, but...

Chromes DevTools is giving me two errors for this code. An Unexpected-end-of-input and an Undefined-function error. These both sound to me like they are being caused by a syntax error, but I can't find it if it's there. Can anyone see a syntax error? Or is there something else I've done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p1 id='txt'></p1>
<button onclick='main();'>Run</button>

<script>
function main(){
    alert('running script');
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=permute([1,2,3]).toString();
}

function permute(list){
    alert('Running permute on '+list.toStriing());
    if(list.length == 1){return [list];}
    if(list.length > 1){
        var perms = [];
        for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            var first = list[i];
            var others = list.slice(0,i).concat(list.slice(i+1,list.length));
            var subPerms = permute(others);
            for(var x=0; x<subPerms; x++){
                perms.push([list].concat(subPerms[x]));
            }
        return perms;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for(var x=0; x<subPerms; x++){ should be    for(var x=0; x<subPerms.length; x++){

Answer (score 2):

1. You are missing a `}` at the end of the outer `for` loop (right before `return perms;`)
2. `toStriing` isn't a function ;)

Answer (score 1):

"unexpected end of input"  errors almost always occur when you are missing a closing bracket or brace.  The parser will continue trying to read past the end of file because the scope hasn't been closed.

This is the case with your code:

`function permute()` does not include a closing brace.

**Solution:** 
Add a single `}` before `</script>`

A good text editor should highlight matching brackets and braces

Answer (score 0):

When you get this message in Javascript, you should check your console, and it should have an error message with an arrow that you can expand. Then, click on the stack trace, and it should give you the line number at which the error occurs
You're missing an outer bracket

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        var first = list[i];
        var others = list.slice(0,i).concat(list.slice(i+1,list.length));
        var subPerms = permute(others);
        for(var x=0; x<subPerms; x++) 
           perms.push([list].concat(subPerms[x]));
        }
        return perms;

 }//you were missing a bracket here
```

Also, you have a `list.toStriing()`. I'm guessing this is just a typo

Your fixed code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p1 id='txt'></p1>
<button onclick='main();'>Run</button>

<script>
function main(){
    alert('running script');
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=permute([1,2,3]).toString();
}

function permute(list){
    alert('Running permute on '+list.toString());
    if(list.length == 1){return [list];}
    if(list.length > 1){
        var perms = [];
        for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            var first = list[i];
            var others = list.slice(0,i).concat(list.slice(i+1,list.length));
            var subPerms = permute(others);
            for(var x=0; x<subPerms; x++){
                perms.push([list].concat(subPerms[x]));
            }
        }
        return perms;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
function main(){
    alert('running script');
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=permute([1,2,3]).toString();
}

function permute(list) {
    alert('Running permute on ' + list.toStriing());
    if (list.length == 1) { return [list]; }
    if (list.length > 1) {
        var perms = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var first = list[i];
            var others = list.slice(0, i).concat(list.slice(i + 1, list.length));
            var subPerms = permute(others);
            for (var x = 0; x < subPerms; x++) {
                perms.push([list].concat(subPerms[x]));
            }
            return perms;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was a missing closing bracket for the permute function. Using a good editor like VS 2013 for syntax proofing is an easy way to avoid mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

toString is misspelled. also, there's a missing curly brace at the end of your permute function. try to always close braces first before writing code to ensure properly closed blocks :)

Answer (score 0):

Closing curly brace for function permute(list){......} is missing and toStriing instead of toString